# Cannot see BDC External system in SharePoint Designer Data Source Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs, bdc-model

I have first created external content types in SharePoint Designer then exported the model to Visual Studio. I then deleted everything created in Designer and deployed the model through SharePoint solution.

When I now go to SharePoint Designer and  try to create a new ECT I cannot see the deployed datasourcei in Data Source Explorer.

I can, however, see BDC model and external system in central administration.

This is part of my bdcm file from SharePoint solution:

```
<Model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog BDCMetadata.xsd" 
Name="MyModel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2007/BusinessDataCatalog">
  <AccessControlList>
    <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT Authority\Authenticated Users">
      <Right BdcRight="Edit" />
      <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
      <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions" />
      <Right BdcRight="SelectableInClients" />
    </AccessControlEntry>
  </AccessControlList>
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Type="Database" Name="MyDB">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="WildcardCharacter" Type="System.String">%</Property>
      </Properties>
      <AccessControlList>
        <AccessControlEntry Principal="NT Authority\Authenticated Users">
          <Right BdcRight="Edit" />
          <Right BdcRight="Execute" />
          <Right BdcRight="SetPermissions" />
          <Right BdcRight="SelectableInClients" />
        </AccessControlEntry>
      </AccessControlList>
      <Proxy />
      <LobSystemInstances>
        <LobSystemInstance Name="MyDB">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="AuthenticationMode" Type="System.String">RdbCredentials</Property>
            <Property Name="DatabaseAccessProvider" Type="System.String">SqlServer</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Data Source" Type="System.String">SQLSERVER</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Initial Catalog" Type="System.String">MyDB</Property>
            <Property Name="RdbConnection Pooling" Type="System.String">True</Property>
            <Property Name="SsoProviderImplementation" Type="System.String">Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreProvider, Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Property>
            <Property Name="SsoApplicationId" Type="System.String">MyDBLogin</Property>
            <Property Name="ShowInSearchUI" Type="System.String"></Property>
          </Properties>
        </LobSystemInstance>
      </LobSystemInstances>
      <Entities>
...
      </Entities>
    </LobSystem>
  </LobSystems>
</Model>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you have to try and edit an existing operation. SharePoint Designer will then prompt you to create new connection.